# How do I import a .bak file into Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Been Googling this for awhile and no answer....can anyone help?

Comment: http://bit.ly/JVv7FQ - tons of results.....

Comment: FYI the procedure hasn't changed. It is the same as with SQL 2005 and 2008.

Comment: @marc_s this question is now #2 on the results :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008, I would imagine the procedure is similar...?

- open SQL Server Management Studio
- log in to a SQL Server instance, right click on "Databases", select "Restore Database"
- wizard appears, you want "from device" which allows you to select a .bak file

Answer (score 6):

Using the `RESTORE DATABASE` command most likely. `bak` is a common extension used for a database backup file. You'll find documentation for this command [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why they removed the option to just right click on the database and restore like you could in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and earlier, but as mentioned above you can restore from a `.BAK` file with:

```
RESTORE DATABASE YourDB FROM DISK = 'D:BackUpYourBaackUpFile.bak' WITH REPLACE
```

But you will want `WITH REPLACE` instead of `WITH RESTORE` if your moving it from one server to another.

Answer (score 1):

`.bak` is a backup file generated in SQL Server.

Backup files importing means restoring a database, you can restore on a database created in SQL Server 2012 but the backup file should be from SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 database.

You restore database by using following command...

```
RESTORE DATABASE YourDB FROM DISK = 'D:BackUpYourBaackUpFile.bak' WITH Recovery
```

You want to learn about how to restore `.bak` file follow the below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script if you don't wish to use Wizard;

```
RESTORE DATABASE myDB
FROM  DISK = N'C:\BackupDB.bak' 
WITH  REPLACE,RECOVERY,  
MOVE N'HRNET' TO N'C:\MSSQL\Data\myDB.mdf',  
MOVE N'HRNET_LOG' TO N'C:\MSSQL\Data\myDB.ldf'
```