# What is the process for importing and viewing a Microsoft SQL Database (.BAK)?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have always worked with a LAMP stack - I'm a bit lost when it comes to Microsoft.

I have been sent a very large Microsoft SQL file (.bak) and I would like to take a look at it (using something like PHPMyAdmin).

What do I need to do from zero to importing/viewing this database (and what tools should I be acquiring/using in order to do so)?

Help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: use this link for help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637958/how-do-i-import-a-bak-file-into-microsoft-sql-server-2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637958/how-do-i-import-a-bak-file-into-microsoft-sql-server-2012)

Comment: This is some other links with steps you need to follow.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837673/how-to-import-a-bak-file-into-sql-server-express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837673/how-to-import-a-bak-file-into-sql-server-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install [`MS SQL Server Express`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSqlServerExpress.aspx)
2. Run `SQL Server Management Studio` and connect to your local instance.
3. Using GUI restore your database(`SQL Server Express` support max 10GB DB).
4. Now you can see DB Objects using Object Explorer and write custom queries.

If your DB is larger than 10GB download `SQL Server Standard`/`Enterprise` trial version.